# Form - passing selected value without parameter name

Tags: javascript, forms, url-parameters

Let's say that I have a very basic form like this:

```html
<form action="https://www.website.com/">
    <select name="1option">
        <option value="A">A</option>
        <option value="B">B</option>
        <option value="C">C</option>
    </select>
    <select name="2option">
        <option value="A">A</option>
        <option value="B">B</option>
        <option value="C">C</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

By having "name" in the select tag, whatever selected option will be generating a URL like this:
https://www.website.com/?option1=A&option2=B

I would like to have the first selected option (option1) to be applied before the list of parameters, like this:

https://www.website.com/A/?option2=B

But I actually don't know how to do it.

Comment: Please include a [mcve] of what you have tried so far to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change action url whenever option1 change like this:

```js
var option = document.querySelector('[data-name="1option"]');
var form = document.querySelector('form');
option.addEventListener('change', function() {
  form.setAttribute('action', 'https://www.website.com/' + option.value);
});
```

```html
<form action="https://www.website.com/">
    <select data-name="1option">
        <option value="A">A</option>
        <option value="B">B</option>
        <option value="C">C</option>
    </select>
    <select name="2option">
        <option value="A">A</option>
        <option value="B">B</option>
        <option value="C">C</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

if you open developer tools you will see that action change and because there are no name for that select it will not be added to query string.

the other option is to add submit event and then change the action attribute.

Comment: @Luca it will not because there are not name attribute, but data-name, it's like id.